# Trying to make user follow another and show notification

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a website in codeigniter and i wants to give a functionality of following other user account. How can I refresh the code using ajax after some specified time? So can somebody give me some easy suggestion to do that  with ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a table notification. When a user followed by another user. You add data in notification table. Table structure is as follows

```
id                       int
image                    text            if you need to show image with notification.
title                    text            Eg. Ram followed you.
link                     text            Link on which you want to redirect.
notification_for         text            user_id of user (sometimes notification is for multiple users)
login_type               text            I use this table for admin/front panel. So I've to use this
created_date             datetime        
created_by               int
updated_date             datetime
updated_by               int
status                   int
```

jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(e){ getnotification();});

function getnotification(){
    $.ajax({
        url         : path/to/post,
        type        : 'POST',
        data        : {'id':id},
        success     : function(e) {
            window.setInterval(function(){getnotification();}, 5000);//run after 5 seconds
        },
    });
}
```